# Good source for TPS and transaction latency / finality for private Ethereum blockchains

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, parity, quorum, benchmark

I am looking for a good source / sources to compare TPS and transaction latency (How long it takes to send a transaction until it is mined) for different private blockchain solutions. Especially I am looking for:

- geth-clique
- quorum
- parity-instantseal
- parity-aura
- (TestRPC)

I know that chainhammer for example does all the TPS tests but I don't find any data on the latency.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to the others as I work on Quorum, but there are a few good sources that our team uses and references.

1. Here is performance evaluation done by an external team with published method and results: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.03421
2. Here is one of the tools we use that tries to standardize a way to submit and measure txn throughput in ethereum like implementations: https://github.com/drandreaskrueger/chainhammer
3. Another tool that may be used is https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper but it will need modding.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. The Quorum evaluation paper was exactly what I am looking for. However, I am missing information for the other implementations (parity, geth). Chainhammer is really useful in terms of transaction throughput but does not seem to provide sufficient information about the transaction latency.